# VR mode (stereo mode) is not working in a WebView for a 360 degree video

Tags: android, webview, google-vr, webvr, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to load the following URL in an Android Webview

URL : http://storage.net-fs.com/hosting/2727323/5/index.htm

The following is the output in a WebView

[image: WebView Loaded as expected]

When clicked on the VR button from top right, I am expecting the below. Which when turned to landscape, plays the video in Stereo mode. This is Working fine as expected, when opened the url in Google Chrome(mobile).

[image: Expecting this prompt][image: Expected stereo mode]

But for me, the video is not playing in VR mode(stereo mode). The following is shown when clicked on VR button.

[image: Actual output]

This is my code

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://storage.net-fs.com/hosting/2727323/5/index.htm");
```

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Have you find any solution? if you find solution, Please post here I have same issue.